# How to add pdf file or text file at local server?

Tags: android

I want to send my file:///mnt/sdcard/APK/Video.apk File to socket and also send pdf and textfile. what is the best way to send these kind of files programetically????

Comment: what do you mean by add to local server!!!

Comment: means I want to share pdf or text file via wifi...and I am developing Wifi file transfer application.I had done sending media files via mediastore but how can I send doc files which are in sdcard? and local server means on my device ip address browser....

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer of my question by myself :-D so here is the solution for who had same question....First I came to know that at server side socket this file path uri not working "file:///mnt/sdcard/APK/Video.apk" or somthing else type of file uri. Only "/mnt/sdcard/APK/Video.apk" is working on socket. So from file uri String which had get from the Content Provider, I had created My File at Server Socket. and then after created a file...I had got also my File Size....

```
private void addSDFileEntity(final Uri uri, HttpResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        if (mTransferStartedListener != null) {
            mTransferStartedListener.started(uri);
        }

        Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null,
                null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NewSDCardContentProvider.SDFiles.Columns.DISPLAY_NAME);

String name = c.getString(nameIndex);
        int dataIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NewSDCardContentProvider.SDFiles.Columns._DATA);
        String dataname = c.getString(dataIndex);
        Uri data = Uri.parse(dataname);




        if (name.endsWith(".pdf")) {
            String contentTypepdf = "application/pdf";
            File myFile = new File(dataname);

            int reqLen = (int) myFile.length();

            Log.d("apk len===>", "" + reqLen);

            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);

            response.addHeader("Content-Type", contentTypepdf);
            response.addHeader("Content-Length", "" + reqLen);
            response.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(fis, reqLen));

            if (socket == null) {
                socket.close();

            }

        }
        if (name.endsWith(".apk")) {
            String contentTypeapk = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
            File myFile = new File(dataname);

            int reqLen = (int) myFile.length();

            Log.d("apk len===>", "" + reqLen);

            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);

            response.addHeader("Content-Type", contentTypeapk);
            response.addHeader("Content-Length", "" + reqLen);
            response.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(fis, reqLen));

        }
```

Now I am sending my File Content at Server Socket....

```
private void sendSDFileContent(
            DefaultHttpServerConnection serverConnection,
            RequestLine requestLine) throws IOException, HttpException {
        HttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(new HttpVersion(1, 1),
                200, "OK");
        String SDfileId = getSDFileId(requestLine.getUri());

        Log.d("selected URI from server", SDfileId);
        addSDFileEntity(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                NewSDCardContentProvider.SDFiles.CONTENT_URI, SDfileId),
                response);
        serverConnection.sendResponseHeader(response);
        serverConnection.sendResponseEntity(response);
    }
```